# Почему значение присваивается всем "строкам" массива

Tags: reactjs

Я хочу, чтобы при нажатии на элемент, на этом элементе появился крестик. Но крестик появляется на всех строках. В консоли вывожу координаты, которые приходят в функцию, видно, что они верные.

Почему это происходит и как это исправить?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: Array(5).fill(Array(5).fill('О')),
        };
    }

    onClick = (i, j) => {
        return () => {
            let data = this.state.data;
            console.clear();
            console.log(i, j);
            
            data[i][j] = 'X';
            this.setState({data});

        }
    };


    render() {
        return (
            <div className="field">
                {this.state.data.map((item, i) => (
                   <div key={`row-${i}`} className="field__row">
                      {item.map((item, j) => <div key={`cell-${j}`} onClick={this.onClick(i, j)} className="field__cell">{item}</div>)}
                   </div>
                ))}
           </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.field {
    font-size: 0;
}

.field__cell {
    position: relative;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: не советую использовать react 15 так он он уже давно устарел используйте 16 ю версию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Почему это происходит

В Вашем внешнем массиве один и тот же одномерный массив добавлен пять раз:

```js
var data = Array(5).fill(Array(5).fill('О'));
data[4][1] = "X";
console.log(data[0][1], data[1][1], data[2][1], data[3][1], data[4][1]);
```

> и как это исправить

Вот так правильно:

```js
var data = (function(){ 
  var result = Array(5).fill({});
  result.forEach((item, ind, arr) => arr[ind] = Array(5).fill('О'));
  return result;
})();
data[4][1] = "X";
console.log(data[0][1], data[1][1], data[2][1], data[3][1], data[4][1]);
```

Спокойствие, только спокойствие. Постарайтесь вникнуть в первую фразу моего ответа. Вот что Вам нужно изменить в Вашем коде:

```
this.state = {
  data: (function(){ 
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      result[i] = Array(5).fill('О');
    return result;
  })()
};
```

Comment: Просто какого черта это происходит. Я беру в вашем примере, 4-й элемент массива, который тоже является массивом, а затем 1-й. Почему это происходит? К тому же, я не хочу создавать новый массив, потому что перетрутся старые значения. Я хочу, конкретной ячейке массива изменить значения, а остальные не трогать.

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо большое! Я все понял!

Comment: @Igor Пожалуйста. Хочу отметить высокое качество вопроса. Поэтому и отвечать на него было приятно.